# Authentification of Android app to Symfony2 doesn't pass

Tags: android, symfony

I'm trying to authentificate on server where Symfony2 app is deployed with Android app. Security system of Symfony is standard:

```
    secured_mobile:
        pattern: ^/mobile
        form_login:
            login_path: mobile_login
            check_path: mobile_login_check
```

Form Andoid app I make a request:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://server/app_dev.php/mobile/login_check");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_username", "user"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_password", "userpass"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

And I get redirected to login page (**mobile_login**).

I even tried to get lodded in by get-request:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://server/app_dev.php/mobile/login_check?_username=user&_password=userpass");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

But it doesn't pass (get redirected to **mobile_login**), although the same url put in browser works!

```
http://server/app_dev.php/mobile/login_check?_username=user&_password=userpass
```

Anybody knows what Symfony needs?

---

**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_MANAGER:     ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_MANAGER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        secured_mobile:
            pattern: ^/mobile
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                post_only: false
                login_path: /mobile/login
                check_path: /mobile/login_check
                default_target_path: /mobile/login_ok
                always_use_default_target_path: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/mobile/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/mobile/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: more security.yml please

Comment: try to add  `methods: [GET, POST]` before `form_login` configuration

Comment: I think there is no problem in symfony configuration. The issue is in Andoid http client which doesn't hold PHP session cookie. I suppose thant when Symfony redirect it to *ogin_ok* after authentification passed it makes query without that cookie and consequently Symfony redirects client back to *login* form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

require_previous_session: false